# Find det(A) for matrix, find C and adj(A)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked to find the determinant of matrix A by using cofactors method. I understand how to do that portion, but then it asks to also find matrix C, and adj(A). How can I go about that?

for det(A) I got -20.

> $ A = \begin{bmatrix}
>         1 & 3 & -3 \\
>         -3 & -3 & 2 \\
>         -4 & 4 & -6 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Do you know how to find the adjugate matrix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: You can choose to calculate the determinant by determining the minors one by one. Then you get the cofactor matrix. You can see my answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2203000/213607 which explains the relation between ${\bf M, C}, \textrm{adj}({\bf A})$ and $\det({\bf A})$

Comment: Okay, so C is just the cofactor matrix then correct? @mathreadler

Comment: I have not read from the source of your problem but I suppose so. In this context $\bf C$ is probably cofactor matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 3 & -3 \\
        -3 & -3 & 2 \\
        -4 & 4 & -6 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$
$\det A = 4$.

We know $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A} adj (A)$, where $adj$ is [adjoint of matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) $A$.

$adj(A)= \left( \begin{array}{ccc} -26 & -30 & -3 \\ 10 & -6 & 7 \\ -24 & -16 & 6 \end{array} \right)$.

$\therefore A^{-1}= \frac{1}{4}\left( \begin{array}{ccc} -26 & -30 & -3 \\ 10 & -6 & 7 \\ -24 & -16 & 6 \end{array} \right)$

$A^{-1}= \left( \begin{array}{ccc} -26/4 & -30/4 & -3/4 \\ 10/4 & -6/4 & 7/4 \\ -24/4 & -16/4 & 6/4 \end{array} \right)$